# Ways to slice a string?

Tags: python

I have a string, example:

```
s = "this is a string, a"
```

Where a `','` (comma) will always be the 3rd to the last character, aka `s[-3]`.

I am thinking of ways to remove the ',' but can only think of converting the string into a list, deleting it, and converting it back to a string. This however seems a bit too much for simple task.

How can I accomplish this in a simpler way?

Comment: I take it string.replace is out of the question? Do you need to preserve other commas in the string?

Comment: I do. Let me go look into string.replace

Comment: replace would be useful, if you need to remove many occurrence of a substr, in this case it will be slower too

Comment: yea, string replace would be ideal if i could start in reverse. I could do x = string.replace(s[::-1], ',', ' ', 1) but that doesn't look to pretty, and whenever i needed to use x, i would have to use as x[::-1] for it to be in its original form =[. Thanks though.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Normally, you would just do:

```
s = s[:-3] + s[-2:]
```

The `s[:-3]` gives you a string up to, but not including, the comma you want removed (`"this is a string"`) and the `s[-2:]` gives you another string starting one character beyond that comma (`" a"`).

Then, joining the two strings together gives you what you were after (`"this is a string a"`).

Comment: Thank you =]. Still open to other suggestions if anyone wants to enlighten

Comment: No, I'm just in it for sharing the love around. But seriously, no, SO doesn't work that way. When I find an answer roughly the same as what I was going to say, I upvote it and sometimes expand. All the rep goes to you. Anyhow, I don't need it, I've come to the realization I will never catch Jon Skeet and even JaredPar is pulling away now that I have to spend more time doing real work :-)

Answer (score 8):

A couple of variants, using the "delete the last comma" rather than "delete third last character" are:

```
s[::-1].replace(",","",1)[::-1]
```

or

```
''.join(s.rsplit(",", 1))
```

But these are pretty ugly.  Slightly better is:

```
a, _, b = s.rpartition(",")
s = a + b
```

This may be the best approach if you don't know the comma's position (except for last comma in string) and effectively need a "replace from right".  However [Anurag's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010961/string-slicing-python/1010973#1010973) is more pythonic for the "delete third last character".

Answer (score 3):

Python strings are immutable. This means that you **must** create at least 1 new string in order to remove the comma, as opposed to editing the string in place in a language like C.

Answer (score 1):

For deleting every ',' character in the text, you can try

```
s = s.split(',')
>> ["this is a string", " a"]
s = "".join(s)
>> "this is a string a"
```

Or in one line:

```
s0 = "".join(s.split(','))
```

Answer (score 0):

The best simple way is : You can use replace function as :-

```
>>> s = 'this is a string, a'
>>> s = s.replace(',','')
>>> s
'this is a string a'
```

Here,   ***replace()*** function search the character ',' and replace it by '' i.e. empty character

Note that , the replace() function defaults all ',' but if you want only replace some ',' in some case you can use :  ***s.replace(',' , '', 1)***

Answer (score 0):

To slice a string of arbitrary length into multiple equal length slices of arbitrary length you could do

```
def slicer(string, slice_length):
    return [string[i:i + slice_length]
            for i in xrange(0, len(string), slice_length)]
```

If slice_length does not divide exactly into len(string) then there will be a single slice at the end of the list that holds the remainder.

Answer (score -2):

s = "this is a string, a"

s= s[:-3] + s[-2:]

print(s)

given s= "this is a string, a"
here s[:-3] gives you a string up to 0 to n-1 which means index number 0 to 15, we don't want a comma next add string s[-2:] which means we add the -2 to -1
**Answer is "this is a string a"**