# How to use re.search as an integer ? Python

Tags: python, string, search

So I have a string

```
s = '>n269412 | AK142815 | msdfhakjfdkjfs'
```

and I want to include everything up to but not including the first instance of '|'

so what I did was

```
import re

p = re.search('|',s)

print s[:p]
```

but i got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

I understand why it isn't working . . because that value is not an integer but is there any way I can use that value where the search found that element ?

Comment: `re.search` returns a match object or None, not an integer.

Comment: ``p = s.find('|')`` or ``p = s.index('|')`` will fit better

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why even bother with a regex for this use-case?

```
s = '>n269412 | AK142815 | msdfhakjfdkjfs'
print s.partition('|')[0]
```

Answer (score 3):

You do not need regular expressions for this:

```
first, rest = s.split('|', 1)
```

Comment: Just to note - where the delimiter is not present - this will raise a `ValueError`

Answer (score 2):

I think `re.match()` gives a more direct solution (i.e. match everything up to and not including the first `|`):

```
In [7]: re.match('[^|]*', s).group(0)
Out[7]: '>n269412 '
```

If there's no `|`, the entire string is returned. It is not entirely clear from the question whether this is what you want.

But as others have said, you don't really need a regex for this...

Answer (score 0):

[`re.search`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) returns [a match object](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects) containing more that just a single index.

What you probably want is the [`start`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match.start) index:

```
>>> s[:p.start()]
'>n269412 '
```

Btw. you need to fix your regular expression as this would just match either `''` or `''` (i.e. nothing). You want to use `'\|'`:

```
p = re.search('\|', s)
```

Answer (score 0):

That error is because re.search returns a MatchObject, which you attempt to slice and cannot do. See the [re.search documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search).

I would do the following:

```
s = '>n269412 | AK142815 | msdfhakjfdkjfs'

# look for the pipe character
findPipe = s.find("|")

# replace everything after the pipe with empty string
s = s.replace(s[findPipe:], "")

print s
```

See [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/the-python-slice-notation) two [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010961/string-slicing-python) for more info about slicing strings.