# How to add +1 to a String that contains letters?

Tags: python, string, integer

For example, if I want to + 1 to the string 'TB004' so it becomes 'TB005'?

To complicate things, the last two digits of 'TB004' must not exceed '12'. once they exceed 12, the last two digits should restart from 00

This is to be looped:

```
for i in range(25):
    #Add 1 to the end of 'TB004', do not exceed 12 as the last two digits, 
    #when you do, restart string with 00 as final numbers.
```

Comment: is there always one-place digit?

Comment: I have not tried anything yet, I have no clue where to start

Comment: write more about your case, it's not clear

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes

Comment: read about string slicing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010961/string-slicing-python

Comment: @Alex, is the entry should always be of length 5?

Comment: ideally, yes. the last two digits should never exceed 12. when they exceed 12, the numbers should become 00 again.

Comment: You can get the last 2 digits from the string and +1 to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
stringhere="TB004"

for i in range(25):
    numberonly=stringhere[2:]
    intointeger=int(numberonly)+1
    if intointeger==12:
        stringhere="TB000"
    else:
        stringhere="TB"+"%03d"%intointeger

    print stringhere
```

Comment: You missed the `should not exceed 12` part

Comment: great!! now how about with the complications I threw into my question?

Comment: `
stringhere="TB004"

for i in range(25):
    numberonly=stringhere[2:]
    intointeger=int(numberonly)+1
    if intointeger==12:
        stringhere="TB000"
    else:
        stringhere="TB"+"%03d"%intointeger

    print stringhere`  
if this is what you want

Answer (score 1):

Use the following approach:

```
s = 'TB011'
ld = int(s[-2:]) + 1
s = '%3s%02d' % (s[:-2], ld if ld <= 12 else 0)

print(s)   # TB012
```

Comment: But what if the input string is `TB009`?

Comment: @kuro, it'll be `TB0010`, so?

Comment: Or should it be `TB010`? The OP can clarify that

Comment: I think we can also split this into a list and if elements in list are ints, to add a number to it

Comment: @kuro, I've added comment

Comment: pythonista solution GREAT