# How to manipulate text in the middle of a string?

Tags: python, string, primitive

How can I concatenate a word within the string at a particular index using Python?
For example:- In the string,

```
"Delhi is the capital of India."
```

I need to concatenate `'123'` before and after 'the'.

The output should be:- `"Delhi is 123the123 capital of India."`

Comment: That’s insertion, not concatenation.

Comment: `str.replace(' the ', ' 123the123 ')`.

Comment: This is not really concatenation, it is more like string manipulation. As @Austin suggested, you can simply replace the in the string using `str.replace()`. We also do not know the scope in which you plan on using this. If you have different strings that have multiple reoccurrences of the word "the" then this particular example would not work for you. Please clarify a bit more on how you plan on using this.

Comment: strings are immutable in python, you only ever can create new strings, f.e. by usint string methods like `replace` or by slicing - see [slice strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010961/ways-to-slice-a-string)

Comment: Thank You everybody for all the information.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `str.replace()` or `.split()` and `enumerate()` to accomplish this

Using *`str.replace()`*

```
s = "Delhi is the capital of India." 
s = s.replace('the', '123the123')
# Delhi is 123the123 capital of India.
```

Using *`.split()`* and *`enumerate()`*

```
s = "Delhi is the capital of India." 
s = s.split()
for i, v in enumerate(s):
    if v == 'the':
        s[i] = '123the123'
s = ' '.join(s)
```

`' '.join()` with a *generator expression*

```
print(' '.join("123the123" if w=="the" else w for w in s.split()))
```

*Further reading*

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem

Comment: Probably could toss a link in there to python documentation as well. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods

Comment: @artomason Done :)

Comment: The `replace` there is the [clbuttic](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem) solution.

Comment: @DavisHerring dont know what clbuttic solution is :/

Comment: (I linked it.)  Your `split` approach can be written as just `"".join("123the123" if w=="the" else w for w in s.split())`.

Comment: @DavisHerring oh wow thats very interesting information and yes, I agree with that `join` statement , it is very nicely condensed you should post it, if not I shall add it in

Comment: @vash_the_stampede: Just edit your answer (and maybe add anti-clbuttic spaces and the Wikipedia link too).

Comment: Thank You very much. @vash_the_stampede

Comment: No prob! Cheers :)